# GTK+2 : My App is Crashing on quit

Tags: c, memory-management, gtk

Hi I'm tying to write  a Simple Text editor and i use this Callback to handle main Window delete-event

```
g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(mainWindow),"delete-event",G_CALLBACK(quit),   (gpointer)textView);
```

this is my callback function to handle this event

```
    void quit(GtkWidget *wid,GdkEvent  *e,gpointer data)
{
    GtkTextIter iStart,iEnd;
    GtkTextBuffer *buffer = gtk_text_view_get_buffer(GTK_TEXT_VIEW(textView));
    gtk_text_buffer_get_bounds(buffer,&iStart,&iEnd);
    gchar * text = gtk_text_buffer_get_text(buffer,&iStart,&iEnd,FALSE);
    if(docFile.isSaved == FALSE && strcmp("",text) )  
    {
        GtkWidget * msgDialog;
        msgDialog = gtk_message_dialog_new(NULL,
                                           GTK_DIALOG_MODAL,
                                           GTK_MESSAGE_QUESTION,
                                           GTK_BUTTONS_YES_NO,
                                           "Do you manna save your file ?",
                                           NULL);

        switch (gtk_dialog_run (GTK_DIALOG(msgDialog)))
        {
            case GTK_RESPONSE_YES:
                if(docFile.name == NULL)
                {
                    if(saveAs(textView))
                    {
                        gtk_widget_destroy (msgDialog);
                        gtk_main_quit ();
                    }
                }
                else
                {   
                    save(textView);
                    gtk_widget_destroy (msgDialog);
                    gtk_main_quit ();
                }
                break;
            case GTK_RESPONSE_NO:
                    gtk_widget_destroy (msgDialog);
                    gtk_main_quit ();

        }
    }else{
            gtk_main_quit();
        }
}
```

but when i'm quit the window i found this in my terminal

```
(Black Hole) adil Tux : SimpleEditor 
>>>> ./a.out 
*** Error in `./a.out': free(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000000604570 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/usr/lib/libc.so.6(+0x7340e)[0x7fefc476a40e]
/usr/lib/libc.so.6(+0x7884e)[0x7fefc476f84e]
/usr/lib/libc.so.6(+0x7900b)[0x7fefc477000b]
./a.out[0x402ad0]
/usr/lib/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7fefc4717040]
./a.out[0x402069]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00404000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 2107681                            /home/adil/Src/SimpleEditor/a.out
00604000-00605000 rw-p 00004000 08:06 2107681                            /home/adil/Src/SimpleEditor/a.out
01a38000-01b83000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
                             [heap]
....

7fefc736b000-7fefc736c000 rw-p 00022000 08:06 920725                     /usr/lib/ld-2.20.so
7fefc736c000-7fefc736d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fff6fd1c000-7fff6fd3d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7fff6fdfc000-7fff6fdfe000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
7fff6fdfe000-7fff6fe00000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
Aborted (core dumped)
```

and thinks you .

Comment: Build with debug info and the callstack will show filenames, function names and line numbers of where the crash happened in your code. You can add debug information by adding the `-g` flag to gcc.

Comment: If you have updated information, then please update your question instead of trying to cram lots of text into a comment.

Answer (score 1):

you have the callback signature for `delete-event` wrong. It is supposed to be return a boolean value to say whether or not the window is deleted.

```
gboolean quit (GtkWidget *wid, GdkEvent *e, gpointer user_data)
{
    . . .
    return TRUE;
}
```

see https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget-delete-event for more details

Answer (score 0):

Giving a quick glance, I can spot that you did not put the `break;` statements at the end of the case `GTK_RESPONSE_YES` and probably you call the `gtk_widget_destroy` and the `gtk_main_quit` functions twice.

Comment: I try putting the break;  but the error is still found i try also delete the gtk_widget_destroy(msgDialog); but no solution thinks a lot anyway :p